# How can I create an absolute url in a jsp?

Tags: jsp, url, jstl

If a have `<c:url value="/article"/>` in a jsp, I actually want it to produce `http://mysite.com/context/article`.  Is there any simple way to acheive this?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175587/absolute-url-in-jsp help?

Comment: No despite the name that shows how to create a url relative to the context root, which does not include the domain.

Comment: Ah - too bad, I didn't realize that. You can use request.getServerName() to get the servername - so if you know the protocol you should be fine with the combination of that and the linked question.

Comment: And use getServerPort() to get the port.

Answer (score 13):

There's no simple way. Either hardcode it or output the following:

```
${fn:replace(pageContext.request.requestURL, pageContext.request.requestURI, '')}${pageContext.request.contextPath}
```

Cumbersome, but there's no shorter/nicer way when you want to take the protocol and port parts of the URL correctly into account. You can at highest assign `${pageContext.request}` to `${r}`.

```
<c:set var="r" value="${pageContext.request}" />
```

so that you can end up with this

```
${fn:replace(r.requestURL, r.requestURI, '')}${r.contextPath}
```

---

That said, I only fail to see how this requirement is useful/valuable. I always code my webapp-specific links to be relative to the current context or to the HTML `<base>` tag. Otherwise you'll have to a lot of maintenance when your domain, port and/or even the context changes. Why this requirement?

#### See also:

- [Is it recommended to use the HTML `<base>` tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag/1889957#1889957) (sensitive subject actually)

Comment: Programming for an application may not be the requirement for needing an absolute URL. Consider a page that may need to provide a permalink to any given page within that site, knowing the base URL could be beneficial. As an aside I see the EWiki software Confluence needs this to be hard coded in it's configuration section for the base URL instead of trying to figure it out.

Comment: how are you referring to static elements such as images, stylesheets, etc.? how do you get to the relative top level?